# Change an excel sheet to be formatted differently

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I'm not really sure of the proper terms here so I didn't know how to search for an answer.

I have a csv file with information presented in the following way:

| Carrier | State |
| --- | --- |
| Aetna Health and Life Insurance Company (AHLIC) | IOWA |
| Aetna Health and Life Insurance Company (AHLIC) | ARIZONA |
| Aetna Health and Life Insurance Company (AHLIC) | UTAH |
| Aetna | CALIFORNIA |
| Aetna | TEXAS |
| Aetna | IDAHO |
| Humana | UTAH |
| Humana | FLORIDA |
| Humana | GEOLRGIA |

I need the information to be presented like so:

| Carrier | State |
| --- | --- |
| Aetna Health and Life Insurance Company (AHLIC) | IOWA, ARIZONA, UTAH |
| Aetna | CALIFORNIA, TEXAS, IDAHO |
| Humana | UTAH, FLORIDA, GEORGIA |

My table has about 2000 rows so I'd prefer to not do it completely manually. What would the best way to accomplish this be?

Comment: vba would be  better than a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you have access to the new array formulas

To get your list of unique values in the first column

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A10)
```

And to join the values associated with each unique value

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(B:B,A:A=D2,""))
```

---

[image]

[image]